# React & Bootstrap 4 Collapse

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I'm importing:

```
import Collapse from "react-bootstrap/es/Collapse";
```

So i'm trying to get my collapse to work in my project here is from the render:

```
<div className="card-header" >
    <a className="card-link" href='#compSci' onClick={this.toggleCollapse}>
        Computer Sciences
    </a>
</div>
<Collapse id="collapse1" isOpen = {this.state.collapse1}>
    <div className="card-body">
        <div className="row">
            {
                computerScience.map(skill => (
                    <div className="col">
                        <SkillPopover skill={skill} />
                    </div>
                ))
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</Collapse>
```

With a toggle collapse function which changes the values from true to false

```
toggleCollapse = () => {
        this.setState({ collapse1: !this.state.collapse1 });
        console.log(this.state.collapse1)
}
```

I'm not quite sure what is going on with this as checking with the debugger it clearly changes the values of the state value collapse 1 between the true and false but it refused to open the Collapse.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT** I'm following a guide here: https://reactstrap.github.io/components/collapse/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my difficulty was that I failed to import the correct bootstrap.  This is a reactstrap component and not a react-bootstrap component.